# Property on static resource converter not bound

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a value converter with a property I would like to bind to, but the binding never happens, i.e. the dependency property in my value converter always is `null`.
Background: I want to bind an enum to a combo box but have control over the text that is being displayed.

I implemented the value converter like this:

```
public class EnumDisplayer : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocalizerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Localizer", typeof(ILocalizer), typeof(EnumDisplayer),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ILocalizer), OnLocalizerChanged));

    public ILocalizer Localizer
    {
        get { return (ILocalizer) GetValue(LocalizerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocalizerProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnLocalizerChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }

    //...
}
```

And I bind it like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Common:EnumDisplayer x:Key="companyTypes"
                          Localizer="{Binding CompanyTypeEnumLocalizer}" />
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl.Resources>
```

My class is an adapted version of the [EnumDisplayer](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-missing-net-7-displaying-enums-in-wpf/).

I fail to understand, why `OnLocalizerChanged` is never called. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Stack Team correct me if I am wrong)... `ValueConverters` do not automatically support in binding and there are reasons...

1. They arent really something that the WPF framework is actively **aware** of, given that they dont lie on visual or logical tree.
2. They are used as part of inner markup extensions. This is a merky area. Unless they implement marrkup extensions on their own, they would be bound to.

Although there are ways..

1. Straightforward way is to use `MultiBinding` instead of single binding. The second binding will replace your converter's need to host a dependncy property.
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachingVirtualBranches.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, it looks like I can't bind to the converter like I thought I could. I am beginning to wonder whether this is the right way? I think it might be better to put all this work in the ViewModel: I give the ViewModel a list with the strings I want to display in the combobox and the property that currently is an enum will be changed to a string. All these strings will be generated by the localizer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be because the `ResourceDictionary` in which you are creating the instance is not part of the visual tree, so it cannot find the `DataContext` and the `Binding` therefore always returns null.

You may be able to get around this by giving your `UserControl` an `x:Name` attribute and then binding using `ElementName` and `DataContext.PropertyName`:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
    <UserControl.Resouces>
        <Common:EnumDisplayer x:Key="companyTypes"
                      Localizer="{Binding DataContext.CompanyTypeEnumLocalizer, ElementName=Root}" />
    </UserControl.Resouces>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Good idea, but this didn't help.